# GPO policy not being added through imported .adm

Tags: customization, windows-server-2003, gpo

I am trying to add an option to the GP Edit console so that I can set the colour of a users background.

I have the following code, which is imported without error, but the policy is not showing.

I also tried changing `categoryname="Desktop"` to `categoryname="TEST"` to see if the file was being read, and the folder 'TEST' was being added, but again with no policy.

Can someone please help me find out what is wrong? Thanks

```
CLASS USER

CATEGORY !!categoryname
KEYNAME "Control Panel\Colors"
    POLICY !!policyname
        EXPLAIN !!explaintext
        PART !!labeltext DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED
            VALUENAME "Background"
            ITEMLIST
                NAME "Black" VALUE "0 0 0"
                NAME "Blue" VALUE "58 110 165"
            END ITEMLIST
        END PART
    END POLICY
END CATEGORY

[strings]
categoryname="Desktop"
policyname="Set the desktop background colour"
explaintext="This policy sets the background colour of the desktop."
labeltext="Choose a colour"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question.

By default, the GP Editor only shows settings that can be fully managed by Group Policy (those that can be set, and that the user cannot change), as opposed to ones those can be partially managed (where GP can set them, but the user can then edit them).

To show both types of policies, follow these steps -

- In the GP Editor, first left click (so that it is in focus) and then right click 'Administrative Templates' under 'User Configuration'.
- Click 'View -> Filtering...'
- Uncheck 'Only show policy settings that can be fully managed'
- Click 'OK', hit 'F5' to refresh the GP Editor, and go look for your policy.

Also see this article on TechNet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739211%28v=ws.10%29.aspx